# Use FromRoute and FromQuery in single action of ApiController in AspNetCore 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

Using ASP.NET Core 2.2 I have the following ApiController action:

```
[ApiController]
public class PostController : Controller 
{

    [HttpGet("posts/{postId:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByPostId([FromQuery]GetByPostIdRequest request) 
    {

    }
}
```

Where `GetByPostIdRequest` is the following:

```
public class GetByPostIdRequest 
{
    [FromRoute]
    public Int32 PostId { get; set; }
    public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public IncludeExpression Include { get; set; }
}
```

The only way all parameters get values are:

1. Have `FromQuery` in action so I don't have the error `Unsupported Media Type`
2. Have `FromRoute` inside the Request class to bind the PostId.

Isn't there another way to do this?

I tried the following, which is logic to me, but does not work:

```
[ApiController]
public class PostController : Controller 
{

    [HttpGet("posts/{postId:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByPostId([FromRoute, FromQuery]GetByPostIdRequest request) 
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: How about another parameter in the action method for the post ID?

Comment: I believe it is better for caching to use the url "posts/postId" and then use parameters to shape the response ... the same, for example, for "categories/categoryId/posts". No?

Comment: I meant another parameter in the action method, e.g. `[FromQuery]GetByPostIdRequest request, [FromRoute]int postId`

Comment: I see ... The point is my service layer accepts only one class of type request so I would need to add ID to the Request inside the controller so it would be one more step.

Comment: I think this might be something to suggest to ASP.NEt Core team, no?

Comment: Your service layer and your UI layer aren't the same thing and perhaps shouldn't be using the same models in the first place.

Comment: I use MediatR (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) so basically a controller receives a GetByPostIdRequest which has parameters. Than an Handler takes that Request and creates one GetByPostIdResponse from data taken from database using or not Entity Framework. I use a vertical arquitecture: one Request per Controller Action ... And one Handler and one Response per Request. This has been the arquitecture that has been proofing to be more scalable. At least on the projects I have been ...

Comment: @DavidG is right.. The correct way to do this is to have an extra parameter.  And there should be a decoupling between your UI Views and your API Models.  You say you have used this architecture in other projects.... Yet it does not work on this one... How come?  And you say it is more scalable.... In what way?  What you are trying to do is hacky in my opinion.  It is not a standard practice.

Comment: What you are saying is to use GetByPostId([FromRoute]postId, [FromQuery]GetByPostIdParameters parameters) { }. Then inside action create a GetByPostIdRequest from both postId and parameters, right? I understand it but there are other problems. Having one object is better for validation and so on ... Not saying that one solution is better than the other ... Just saying that both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: When I said better arquitecture I meant have One Handler per One Request. I do not have a service with methods like GetPostById ... I have one handler that handles GetPostByIdRequest  another that handlers GetPostByNameRequest and so on ... Each Handler receives one unique Request. And returns one unique Response. Now if that Request is exactly what you can in the Controller action that is another point. And I understand your point.

Comment: For example, I also have a GetPostByNameRequestValidator that handles GetPostByNameRequest validation ... Until ApiController in Asp.Net Core 2.2 this worked fine ... And in ApiController works fine to ... just having FromRoute inside the Request does not seem the most elegant solution. Just that

Answer (score 0):

This is the package what you might be looking for: [HybridModelBinding](https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding).

It solves the problem of mixed model binding in ASP.NET by using the [FromHybrid] attribute. Your model will get bound with data from the body of a request, and then get updated with data from route or querystring-attributes.

```
[ApiController]
public class PostController : Controller 
{

    [HttpGet("posts/{postId:int:min(1)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByPostId([FromHybrid]GetByPostIdRequest request) 
    {
    }

}
```